# Can I detect the orientation of an image with text in c# - possibly using MODI?

Tags: c#, orientation, ocr, modi

I have a number of documents scanned to png files.  I do not know the orientation of each scan.  I need to know how much to rotate them when I present them to the user; either 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees.  The documents are in English.

I am using MODI to extract text from each image in a .net 4.0 c# environment.  Is there a way to read the orientation of the image using MODI?  Or perhaps another method accessible from c# to detect the orientation of the image?

Answer (score -1):

Why use method? Just check the sizes:

```
if(img.width>img.height)
    //orientation=landscape
else
    //orientation=portait
```

Comment: Using this method will tell me if the document is in landscape, but will not tell me whether to rotate it 90 or 270 degrees.  I have a 50/50 chance of displaying the document upside down.